# How do I install on Windows 11?

Tags: drush, 9, installation

I wish to install Drupal 9 on Windows 11 using Drush.

*Drupal on the cloud* solutions (which should be easily accessible from Windows) cost money and not quite what I seek for a local install.
I can install Drupal 9 on WAMP/XAMPP on Windows but I don't want because it doesn't have Drush (and I don't think [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) will help).
I can install Linux, either directly or on a virtual machine, using a distribution like Ubuntu, which I have used over the years, but I encounter several keyboard and mouse issues (slow mouse scrolling, keyboard input problems, etc.) which make hard for me to edit much content.

How do I install Drupal 9 with Drush on Windows 11?

Comment: This is great you have years of experience running Drupal on Ubuntu. In a virtual machine  you have either performance problems with file sharing or keyboard/mouse issues when accessing the Linux desktop via VNC. So install the IDE (VS Code or PHPstorm) on Windows and connect the Linux VM via SSH. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Comment: Hello @4uk4 what is VNC? I use VirtualBox as a machine. Please consider to publish an answer with steps for newbies like myself.

Comment: Start using a Docker-based setup like DDEV: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. Everything will happen in the containers then and you don't have to mess w/ your Windows. Having drush/drush in your composer.json, execute `ddev composer install` once and from then on use `ddev drush updb` etc.

Comment: @leymannx but where do I install this Docker-based setup? On Windows 11 itself? On Docker Desktop?

Comment: VNC is what you are using now, having the keyboard/mouse issues. My advice is to move away from it. Once you have the Linux VM running (as you say you know how to do it and then you can do it without docker), then the only thing you need are the steps described in the VS code link.

Comment: Read the DDEV docs, please. It will enlighten you. DDEV requires Docker (Desktop). You install DDEV and then get a bunch of commands to do stuff inside the DDEV containers.

Comment: Don't use a VirtualBox - use WSL2.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu as VirtualBox machine (for other reasons), but I have never had keyboard/mouse issues. With GNOME, it's necessary to set VirtualBox with 3D acceleration, or it will start to be slow. That's GNOME, though. Using a different DE doesn't create any issue. It's probable you are using VNC; that would cause issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows 11, you should consider using Docker with WSL2.  This will let you use a WSL installation of Ubuntu, which runs in the hypervisor and will give better performance than a virtual machine in VirtualBox, etc.

However, with WSL2 (different from WSL1), filesystem performance will take a huge hit if you manipulate linux files from Windows. To get around this, you can set up Visual Studio Code or PHPStorm in Windows to access your WSL2 environment.  Alternately, you can install the IDE of your choice in WSL2 and run it with wslg support, but this is harder to set up and prone to graphical glitches.

Personally, if you are comfortable with Ubuntu, I would recommend using a docker-based solution inside WSL2 like [lando](https://lando.dev/).  Lando provides a nice interface for setting up docker containers and has great support out of the box for Drupal as well as many of the Drupal PaaS.

So the basic flow is:

1. Install Ubuntu and upgrade it to WSL2 (it will probably be WSL1 by default).
2. Install docker and lando in WSL2 and set up your drupal site.
3. Install your IDE (assuming it is VSCode or PHPStorm) in Windows and then connect to WSL.
4. Enjoy a complete linux environment from Windows with great performance.

All of the software recommended here is open source (except PHPStorm) and freely available.  lando has been around for 10+ years (used to be called Kalabox) and WSL has been around since 2016 and continues to get big upgrades from Microsoft (it's the basis for Windows 11's Android app compatibility), so although it takes time to set this up, you can be reasonably confident that these solutions will continue to be supported well into the future.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I have only one Drupal website to work on. My personal website. Do I still need Docker? Isn't docker a tool for people who wish to start off from a certain Drupal state/mode when building many Drupal sites for customers?

Comment: Docker is used in complicated deployment setups, but it can also be used easily for a single site.  You said you wanted a local dev setup, which lando (and other docker-based dev tools like ddev and docksal) provide out of the box.  With these tools, you can install lando and then use the `drupal9` recipe (https://docs.lando.dev/config/recipes.html) to quickly set up the db and webserver in docker automatically. This is very similar to WAMP but it uses docker as the base, which is generally faster than WAMP in a VM due to containers (using lando, you don't have to worry about the details).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to install Drupal 9 on [windows 11](https://www.howtogeek.com/category/windows-11/) then follow these steps which are given on drupal.org Step 1: Get the Code
Install the files you need to run Drupal.

Step 2: Install dependencies with composer
If you installed or updated the codebase using git, then install required PHP libraries with composer.

Step 3: Create a database
Create a database for Drupal to use.

Step 4: Configure your installation
Set up the web server and PHP to work together.

Step 5: Run the installer
Run the installation script.

Step 6: Status check
Check the status of your site at Administration > Reports > Status report. Set trusted hosts patterns, create files directories.

Add Composer to an existing site
How to convert an existing Drupal site to a composer-managed project. Step by step guide to adding composer to manually installed site.

Building a Drupal site with Git
How to use Git to manage the source code for a Drupal site

Drupal Quick Start Command
Launch a local demo version of Drupal.

Trusted Host settings
Protecting against HTTP HOST Header attacks

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Have a look at the help center to find out more about how to write [good answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). This answer does not address the question of how to install drush. It is also lacking links to resources, e.g. to drupal.org, and could easily be improved by better formatting.

Answer (score -3):

I have found the way to install (and upgrade) Drupal 9 and above on Windows 11 extremely cumbersome and not worth the time.

An alternative, for those who need Windows 11 mechanics and keyboard behavior is to hire a shared hosting (which includes SSH and Composer) and install Drupal on that shared hosting while SSHing to this environment from Windows 11.
If working this way, it's probably best to put the website on maintenance mode and `disallow: /` in robots.txt for development time.

If one takes the path I have suggested, while working form Windows 11 the installation pretty much narrows down to the following steps:

```shell
# Configure DNS records
# Configure database (say, with PHPMyAdmin)

cd WEB_APPLICATION_ROOT
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
cd WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
composer require drush/drush
vendor/bin/drush site:install

# Configure web_application_root (example.com/web, done from "domains" in Cpanel)
# Install Drupal from web browser
```

Comment: Everyone is encouraged to use Docker based solutions, especially for Windows, vs trying to script and install these things directly which is far more complicated with Windows over other operating systems. This also presumes people have some knowledge of hosting a server before they get this far - most don't. `It is a fact of life that this is one way to work with Drupal in Windows 11` - no, this is 'working' with Drupal on a Linux host.

Comment: @Kevin from my experience using Docker is far more complicated than this solution and in practice it's working both on Windows and Linux...

Comment: DDEV, Docksal and Lando are specifically tailored for this and pitched on drupal.org, Acquia, Pantheon, etc.